# SpringBoot unit test cannot load yml file

Tags: java, spring-boot, testing, yaml

when i try to test springboot program, it cannot find application.yml file.but when i change it to application.properties, it work well.

I tried a lot of methods and couldn't solve the problem very well.It seems that there is only one solution, that is to use the .properties file.

The testCode ：

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest
public class VizServerApplicationTests {

    @Test
    public void contextLoads() {
    }
}
```

Error Message：

```
    Could not resolve placeholder 'spring.datasource.url' in value 
    "${spring.datasource.url}"
```

Comment: What versions are you using? Could you share some more details?

Comment: the springboot version is  2.1.1.release , and the test maven is   spring-boot-starter-test

Comment: Try to see if env-variables are getting loaded, as a first step. If  "spring.datasource.url" is not listed, look into why it's not loaded/listed. Env variables can be set via prop-file or export command.  Enable debug mode and read logs.

Comment: It seems that the application.yml file is not parsed correctly(just in unit test).when  I use application.properties file, it work well.

Comment: I can't imagine that something this basic would be broken, but without more information, logging or more configuration we can't do anything. The best would be a minimal project which shows the problem, it's not likely that anyone will be able to help you otherwise :-)

Answer (score 0):

The file should be named `.yml`

Source: https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-external-config.html#boot-features-external-config-application-property-files

> You can also use YAML ('.yml') files as an alternative to '.properties'.

Comment: Yes, the spelling is wrong in the title. the application.yml file  is not work